# Running MG996R servo using Eneloop Pros

Tags: batteries, servo, arduino-uno

Recently I just bought 2 pack of Eneloop pros, and have fully charged it. By using a multimeter I saw that the voltage went up to 1.3 ish after it is fully charged. And I'm planning on using 5 of them (in series) to power 5 different MG996R servos which has an operating voltage of 4.8 to 7.2v

So 1.3v x 5 = 6.5v

Is it possible that I could burn out the servos because I used the voltage closer to 7.2v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A servo burns out if it is mechanically overloaded (stuck) because then it gets hot. If it is not stuck then it will be fine on your 6.5V.

Comment: Ahh i see thx thn